# tabular doesn't give two equally-size figures

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I have produced two boxplots.

`Amplification.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Amplitude of Focal and Arm-level SCNAs},ylabel = {$log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Focal, Arm}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0.1000546,
      lower quartile=0.1615851,
      median=0.2402481,
      upper quartile=0.4031734,
      upper whisker=0.7642697
    }, color = red
    ] table[col sep=comma] {FocalAmpRemaining.csv};
     \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
     lower whisker=0.1035846,
     lower quartile=0.1141071,
     median=0.1301499,
     upper quartile=0.2035154,
     upper whisker=0.2652706
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates {(0,0.4313409)};
    \draw[black, dashed]
      (axis cs:0, 0.1) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and `deletion.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [title = {Deletion of Focal and Arm-level SCNAs},ylabel = {$log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Focal, Arm}
    ]
    \addplot+[mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=-0.9197604,
      lower quartile=-0.4621040,
      median=-0.2362183,
      upper quartile=-0.1566109,
      upper whisker=-0.1003486
    }, color = blue 
    ] coordinates {};
     \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
     lower whisker=-0.2970707,
     lower quartile=-0.2019435,
     median=-0.1603655,
     upper quartile=-0.1199740,
     upper whisker=-0.1012605
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates {(0,-0.3299711)(0,-0.3299711)(0,-0.3642782)(0,-0.3930741)(0,-0.4372732)(0,-0.6161027)};
     \draw[black, dashed]
      (axis cs:0, -0.1) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I saved both pictures as pdfs, re-uploaded them into latex, and tried to assemble them using `tabular`. However, they are not sized equally. How could that be? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\begin{document}        
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{amplification.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{deletion.pdf} \\
{\Large\textbf{(A)}} & {\Large\textbf{(B)}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you want to include them in a tabular? You can typeset tikzpictures (including plots) in a document directly without including the "images".

Comment: Hi! It's because I don't know how to add (A)  and (B) otherwise. I first found tabular, and it worked for other figures but not this one... Could you please suggest an alternative? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that your charts are different aspect ratios (I can't know because I don't have your csv so I can't recreate them), so setting them to be the same width won't make them the same height. Note that the left side of your left chart has one digit wide labels, but the right-hand chart has four character wide labels—that's probably the difference. You could specify both the width and the height for the plots, but that's a bad solution because it will stretch them.

The easiest way would be to set them to be the same height instead, which would make it look right:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\begin{document}        
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-1x1.pdf} &
        \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image.pdf} \\
        {\Large\textbf{(A)}} & {\Large\textbf{(B)}} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

But in a document, your table method will mess with your margins, and since you specified a paper size and `twoside` it sounds like you wanted a document?

For that case you might want to put them next to each other manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}

\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\begin{document}  
    This causes all sorts of margin problems:\bigskip


    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-1x1.pdf} &
        \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image.pdf} \\
        {\Large\textbf{(A)}} & {\Large\textbf{(B)}} \\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{.5in}

    So it may be better to place them manually:\bigskip

    \noindent\includegraphics[height=2.25in]{example-image-1x1}\hfill
    \includegraphics[height=2.25in]{example-image}\par
    \noindent{\Large\textbf{(A)}}\hspace{2in}{\Large\textbf{(B)}}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

I used `\usepackage{mwe}` for this example because it loads test images in all common LaTeX distributionst to make things like this easy to share. They're example pdfs no different (except for the shape) than the ones you created.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry for not seeing it, but I don't see what you mean by 1 character wide and 4 character wide...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupplots`. Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass[margin=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics,groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group name=my plots,group size=2 by 1, vertical sep=70pt,horizontal sep=6em,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title = {\strut Deletion of Focal and Arm-level SCNAs},ylabel = {$log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Focal, Arm},
    width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      %scale only axis,
%      scaled ticks = false,
    ]
    \addplot+[mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=-0.9197604,
      lower quartile=-0.4621040,
      median=-0.2362183,
      upper quartile=-0.1566109,
      upper whisker=-0.1003486
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates {};
     \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {blue},
    boxplot prepared={
     lower whisker=-0.2970707,
     lower quartile=-0.2019435,
     median=-0.1603655,
     upper quartile=-0.1199740,
     upper whisker=-0.1012605
    }, color = blue
    ] coordinates {(0,-0.3299711)(0,-0.3299711)(0,-0.3642782)(0,-0.3930741)(0,-0.4372732)(0,-0.6161027)};
     \draw[black, dashed]
      (axis cs:0, -0.1) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp);
   \nextgroupplot [title = {\strut Amplitude of Focal and Arm-level SCNAs},ylabel = {$log_{2}(I_{C}/I_{N})$},
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Focal, Arm},
    width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      %scale only axis,
%      scaled ticks = false,
    ]
    \addplot+[mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0.1000546,
      lower quartile=0.1615851,
      median=0.2402481,
      upper quartile=0.4031734,
      upper whisker=0.7642697
    }, color = red
    ] table[col sep=comma] {FocalAmpRemaining.csv};
     \addplot+[mark = *,mark options = {red},
    boxplot prepared={
     lower whisker=0.1035846,
     lower quartile=0.1141071,
     median=0.1301499,
     upper quartile=0.2035154,
     upper whisker=0.2652706
    }, color = red
    ] coordinates {(0,0.4313409)};
    \draw[black, dashed]
      (axis cs:0, 0.1) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp);
    \end{groupplot}
    \node[below=8mm,font=\bfseries\large] at (my plots c1r1.south) {(A)};
    \node[below=8mm,font=\bfseries\large] at (my plots c2r1.south west) {(B)};  %% change south west as you wish
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `width` and `height` same for both the plots and also added a `\strut` in the titles (because one of titles has `p` the other has no descenders).